# Required field validation for kendo-dropdownlist in angular 7 application

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to implement required field validation for kendo-dropdownlist on my template driven form in angular 7. If you can see I am looping and generating a dynamic table which has kendo dropdownlist in every row. I need to highlight the dropdown if it is not selected. I tried to enclose my divs withing a form tag thinking I could handle it when the user presses submit but I think this is more of setting within kendo. Could somebody tell me the way to do it. Whatever examples I am seeing so far all jquery based.

Here is the stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4v2k8f

Html

```
form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && createDocument()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
<div class="center" class="file-upload-wrapper">
    <ngx-file-drop dropZoneLabel="Drop files here" dropZoneClassName="file-drop" multiple="true"
        (onFileDrop)="dropped($event)" (onFileOver)="fileOver($event)" (onFileLeave)="fileLeave($event)">
        <ng-template ngx-file-drop-content-tmp let-openFileSelector="openFileSelector">
            <button type="button" (click)="openFileSelector()">Drop Files to Upload</button>
        </ng-template>
    </ngx-file-drop>

    <div class="upload-table">
        <table id="table1" class="center">

            <tbody class="upload-name-style">
                <tr *ngFor="let item of files; let i=index">
                    <td> <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="item.relativePath" style="width: 350px" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:350px" [(ngModel)]="item.selectedDocumentItem" 
                            [data]="DocumentTypes" [defaultItem]="defaultItem" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                            valueField="Id">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <kendo-datepicker style="width: 200px" [format]="'dd MMM, yyyy'"
                            [(ngModel)]="item.selectedDate"></kendo-datepicker>
                    </td>
                    <td> <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="deleteRow(i)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete
                        </button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button *ngIf="files.length > 0" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-upload">upload</button>
    </div>
</div>


</form>
```

Component

```
 public createDocument() {
        this.files.forEach(element => {

            this.uploadDocument = <IDocument>{

                id: 5508,
                documentTypeId: element.selectedDocumentItem.Id ,
                name: element.relativePath,
                documentDate: element.selectedDate

              };


        });
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz example of that?

Comment: Here you got with the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4v2k8f

Comment: what about isRequired ? look at the documentation : https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/forms/#toc-reactive-forms

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need is use a reference variable and see if is valid or not. I put a simple example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufkcvk-v2cyrl?file=app/app.component.ts). As you only want to know if has a valid, you can use simple required. My stackblitz is like

**Update**: in a form, disabled the button submit

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="example-wrapper">
    <form #myForm="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="let item of files; let i=index">
      <p>T-shirt size:</p>
      <kendo-dropdownlist name="select{{i}}" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="value[i]" [data]="listItems" required>
      </kendo-dropdownlist>
      <span *ngIf="name.invalid">*</span>
    </div>
    <button [disabled]="myForm.invalid">submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public listItems: Array<string> = ["X-Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large", "2X-Large"];
    value=[]
    files=[{value:''},{value:''},{value:''}]
}
```

Briefly explain (but you has the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#template-driven-validation))
When we has a [(ngModel)] we can use a template reference to refer to the input. If we equal the template reference to ngModel `#name="ngModel"`, we can use in the .html the template variable and all the properties of ngModel (invalid, touched...) in the way, `name.invalid`, `name.touched`...

Ah!, don't worry about you are put the "same" reference variable, if the variable of the model is not equal, Angular understand that they are diferents variables.

NOTE: Personally, I suggest you use ReactiveForms and FormArray, but it's only an opinion

**Update 2** Really The problem is that you can not loop over the same list that you want modified. You has `*ngFor="let item of files"` and you're changing `files`. the trick is iterate over `' '.repeat(files.length).split('')` -or create an array in code- `this.iterator=new Array(this.files.length)`, then you can do `<tr *ngFor="let t of iterator;let i=index">`

The [(ngModel)] is over files[i].selectedDocumentItem.Id

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufkcvk-ygzj1h?file=app/app.component.ts) and the code

```
<div class="example-wrapper">
    <form #myForm="ngForm">
        <!-- other way is <tr *ngFor="let t of iterator;let i=index"> -->
        <tr *ngFor="let t of ' '.repeat(files.length).split(''); let i=index">
            <td>
                <kendo-dropdownlist name="select{{i}}" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="files[i].selectedDocumentItem.Id" [defaultItem]="files[i].selectedDocumentItem.id"
                 [data]="DocumentTypes" [valuePrimitive]="true" textField="Name" valueField="Id" required>
                </kendo-dropdownlist>
                <span *ngIf="name.invalid">*</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <button [disabled]="myForm.invalid">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

If we want use as [ngModel]=files[i].selectedDocumentItem (an object), we need create a customError directive. It's looks like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[requiredId]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: RequiredIdDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class RequiredIdDirective implements Validator {

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
    return control.value.Id?null:{required:true}
  }
}
```

And our dropdown is now like

```
<kendo-dropdownlist name="select{{i}}" #name="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="files[i].selectedDocumentItem" 
      [defaultItem]="files[i].selectedDocumentItem" 
      [data]="DocumentTypes" 
      textField="Name" valueField="Id" requiredId>
      </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

See a new [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufkcvk-cbgmyb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I didnt get your example.  I basically need the preventing the user from clicking the button until the value is selected or display a message next to the control to say the value is not selected or hightlight the control

Comment: if we want a button submit that is disabled, add tag `<form #myForm="ngForm">`, add name to the inputs (in this case must be different) and put a button `<button [disabled]="myForm.invalid">submit</button>`, just corrected in answer and in stackblitz. Note: I recomended you read the officials docs: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: for me it's working, only when you select all the dropdowns, you can use "submit" button. If a dropdown not has no value selected, a `*` is at the side of it :(

Comment: I meant i am not able to open the link itself.Can you check again please

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufkcvk-v2cyrl?file=app/app.component.ts I put for copy and paste: `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufkcvk-v2cyrl?file=app/app.component.ts`

Comment: Its till blank window.Could you select share a link and then share

Comment: editor URL:`https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufkcvk-v2cyrl`, appURL: `https://angular-ufkcvk-v2cyrl.stackblitz.io`

Comment: anyway, in page https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/ Open in stackblitz the simple example, add in app module `import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'` and add it in `ìmports`and copy and paste the code

Comment: the appURL is opening but not the first link. Could you tell me one thing. I am referring to the html that you have shared in the post. I guess it should be the same. When I implement as it is , I get error saying ngModelOptions should be applied as the name is not set. When i set the ngModelOptions to standalone then nothing works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196327/discussion-between-tom-and-eliseo).

Comment: Can you please see my private chat please

Comment: Why dropdown is not "red-bordered" on init and "borders" only on focusout?

Comment: I suppose the class that make the "red-bordered" is "ng-invalid ng-touched", and Angular only add the class "ng-touched" on focusout. Try mark all as touched, https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAllAsTouched. After the form is created and give values use `this.yourForm.markAllAsTouched()`